# Swift: Trouble Using Enums Declared in Objective-C, In Swift

Tags: objective-c, enums, swift

OK. Looked at the various answers when I typed out the question, and don't see the answer listed.

This seems such a basic, fundamental issue that I *MUST* be doing something wrong, but I am being driven crazy (actually, not much of a "drive." More of a short putt) trying to figure out what I am getting wrong.

I have created a test project [that can be downloaded here](http://magshare.net/junk/TestBridgeFromC.zip) (small project).

In any case, I encountered this, when working on importing a large Objective-C SDK that I wrote into Swift.

Everything works great. Until... I try to do comparisons on enums declared in C.

Obviously, C enums are not turned into Swift enums, but I am having trouble figuring out how to use them.

Here's a sample of what you will see in the test project;

I have a couple of C files that declare enums:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum
{
    StandardEnumType_Undef  = 0xFF,
    StandardEnumType_Value0 = 0x00,
    StandardEnumType_Value1 = 0x01,
    StandardEnumType_Value2 = 0x02
} StandardEnumType;

typedef NS_ENUM ( unsigned char, AppleEnumType )
{
    AppleEnumType_Undef  = 0xFF,
    AppleEnumType_Value0 = 0x00,
    AppleEnumType_Value1 = 0x01,
    AppleEnumType_Value2 = 0x02
};

StandardEnumType translateIntToEnumValue ( int inIntValue );
int translateEnumValueToInt ( StandardEnumType inValue );

AppleEnumType translateIntToAppleEnumValue ( int inIntValue );
int translateAppleEnumValueToInt ( AppleEnumType inValue );
```

The functions mentioned do pretty much what it says on the tin. I won't include them.

I did the bridging header and all that.

I am trying to use them in the initial load of the Swift app:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool
    {
        let testStandardConst:StandardEnumType = translateIntToEnumValue ( 0 )

//        Nope.
//        if ( testStandardConst.toRaw() == 0 )
//        {
//            
//        }

//        This don't work.
//        if ( testStandardConst == StandardEnumType_Value0 )
//        {
//            
//        }

//        Neither does this.
//        if ( testStandardConst == StandardEnumType_Value0.toRaw() )
//        {
//            
//        }

//        Not this one, either.
//        if ( testStandardConst.toRaw() == StandardEnumType_Value0 )
//        {
//            
//        }

        let testAppleConst:AppleEnumType = translateIntToAppleEnumValue ( 0 )

//        This don't work.
//        if ( testAppleConst == AppleEnumType.AppleEnumType_Value0 )
//        {
//            
//        }

//        Neither does this.
//        if ( testAppleConst == AppleEnumType.AppleEnumType_Value0.toRaw() )
//        {
//            
//        }

//        Nor this.
//        if ( testAppleConst == .AppleEnumType_Value0 )
//        {
//            
//        }

        return true
    }
```

I can't seem to get the $#@!! enums to compare to either ints or anything else.

I am often humbled by the stupid errors I make, and sometimes need them pointed out to me, so please humble me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When working with `typedef NS_ENUM` enums in swift you should omit enum name in comparison and assignment, here how you can compare it:

```
if ( testAppleConst == .Value0 ) { ... }
```

You can read more about this in Apple do s for Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_15).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, and it don't work. There seems to be something whacky about enums declared in C. This is an issue, because the C header file that I am using has a couple hundred standard C typedef enums, and it is a pain to work with.

Comment: That is strange because I've downloaded the project that you've shared and tried in it... What version of xCode do you use?

Comment: Xcode 6 beta 4. Did you uncomment the last example? That was the one I tried. In any case, I'm trying it out, just in case I missed something. What I get is that AppleEnumType doesn't have a member named "AppleEnumType_Value0".

Comment: D'oh! It works if I remove the enum header (AppleEnumType_), and leave the trailing enum stuff. That is weird. Your answer is correct, but it also means that I need to strip off the enum prefix.

Comment: Unfortunately, this means that I have to go through all couple hundred of my enums, and convert them to use the NS_ENUM macro. sigh... Thanks so much!

Comment: Problem with pure C enum looks weird for me as well. I was surprised that it was not converted to Swift enum automatically. You can post feature request/or bug to Apple https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: OK. I talked this over with my co-workers, and we figured this makes sense. It's an issue of scope. The reason for the ObjC convention, is because all C enums are in the global scope, while Swift has a local namespace for each enum. This means that we don't need to prefix the enum name to the value. It's annoying (but not a dealbreaker) that they won't translate standard enums. Now that I know what the issue is, I can live with it.