# Objective-C enum in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have the following enum in an Objective-C file:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, countDirection){
    countDirectionUp = 0,
    countDirectionDown
};
```

How can I use this in a Swift view controller? I have tried this:

```
label.countDirection = countDirection.countDirectionDown
```

but I get an error:

> `countDirection.Type does not have a member named countDirectionDown`

Comment: Are you using a bridging header or are you trying to re-create the typedef in your Swift class?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017487/swift-trouble-using-enums-declared-in-objective-c-in-swift? – It should be `label.countDirection = countDirection.Down` or just `label.countDirection = .Down`.

Comment: @MartinR,  That doesn't work for me: *countDirection.Type does not have a member named 'Down'* (Xcode 6.3.2)

Comment: @7stud: It does work for me. But how did you define `label` ?

Comment: @MartinR, I didn't define `label`.  I just bridged the objc enum in a swift app, and I tried to create a variable of the enum type and assign it one of the enum values.

Comment: @7stud: `var foo : countDirection; foo = .Down` compiles without problem for me.

Comment: @MartinR, What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @7stud: Tested with code Xcode 6.4 (the current version) and Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: @MartinR, Hey, now your code is working for me!  That's really frustrating because I copy and pasted from my enum definition, so there would be no spelling errors.  I've noticed this problem in the past too, where I'll run code several times and get errors and then the 4th or 5th time I run the code, no errors.   Do you have to explicitly save the file?  I thought Xcode automatically saved the file before running the code.

Comment: @MartinR: It was probably my fault.  The op's code definitely causes an error.   But when I tried your code, I think I might have been using different enum values than the op's, so your code didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have tried this, but no luck. I am using xCode 7 beta. Same error!

I am using a bridging header.

Comment: I have working code, I needed: `countDirection.CountDirectionDown.rawValue`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These get translated to

```
countDirection.Up
countDirection.Count
```

Swift removes as many letters as possible that the enum values have in common with the enumeration name. In your case, with an enumeration called countDirection and a value countDirectionUp, the whole "countDirection" is removed. It's not needed because you know which enum you are using, making your code considerable shorter.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In Swift 4, Swift will also make the first character of each enumeration item lowercase. Therefore, in the code example above it would be `countDirection.up`, for example.

Comment: Saved my life. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With a bridging header and your enum values, I get the same error you do.  However, if I change the enum values to:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, countDirection) {
    cdUp = 0,
    cdDown

};
```

...then I don't get any errors.  For some reason, Swift does not like enum values that begin with the type name.

No error with these enum values either:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, countDirection) {
    CountDirectioUp = 0,
    CountDirectionDown
};
```

Comment: *"Swift does not like enum values that begin with the type name."* – No, this is wrong. Swift *does* like them an imports them in an optimized way. Have a look at the "Enumerations"  section in "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C". Most enum definitions in the Foundation framework use that pattern.

Comment: Swift uses a very useful system to abbreviate enum values, and you are working hard against it. No wonder you don't get good results.