# Using NS_Option Enum declared in objective C in Swift Project

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have enum NS_OPTION declared in Objective C as such

```
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, PHRendererType)
{
    PHRendererTypeSampleBuffer,
    PHRendererTypeOpenGLES,
    PHRendererTypeQuartz
};
```

however, when i try to use in Swift project by calling.

```
if rendererType == .PHRendererTypeSampleBuffer{

}
```

it fails to compile with error : Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

I have also visited this topic [Swift: Trouble Using Enums Declared in Objective-C, In Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017487/swift-trouble-using-enums-declared-in-objective-c-in-swift) but it did not solve my problem

Thanks for any help.

Comment: some context to `renderedType`?

Comment: Are you creating a bitmask or standard enum? Perhaps you meant to declare it as “typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, PHRendererType)”  https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewBook?id=88889477

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked to did provide a solution to your problem:

```
if rendererType == .SampleBuffer {

}
```

When you define your enum as `NS_OPTIONS(type, EnumPrefix)`, remove the `EnumPrefix` from all references in Swift. However, be aware that this shortcut will not be valid the moment you break the naming convention in Objective-C:

```
// 1.
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, PHRendererType)
{
    PHRendererTypeSampleBuffer,
    PHRendererTypeOpenGLES,
    PHRendererTypeQuartz,
    SomethingElse
};

// Now you have to use the full enum name:
if renderedType == .PHRendererTypeSampleBuffer { }


// 2. Follow the naming convention and you can use the shortcut again:
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, PHRendererType)
{
    PHRendererTypeSampleBuffer,
    PHRendererTypeOpenGLES,
    PHRendererTypeQuartz,
    PHRendererTypeSomethingElse
};

if renderedType == .SomethingElse { }
```